# How to segue normal UIViewController that don't have tab bar to UIViewController that have tab bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I'm developing iOS App.

My App has 6 button and each button has each tab bar controll.

```
so Main screen is
```

[btn1]   [btn2]

[btn3]   [btn4]

[btn5]   [btn6]

===================
this screen doesn't have tab bar controll.

but if I get into btn1

============================

table view

[tab1][tab2][tab3][tab4]

============================

btn1's screen has tab bar controll like this.

how can I get each different tab respectively to each button.

Main screen shouldn't have tab bar controll.

Is anyone who know the similar problem link or solution?

help me plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the ViewController you are segueing to (in storyboard), then in XCodes Menubar select Editor -> Embed in -> TabBarController

if I misunderstood you question: a (commented) screenshot of your Storyboard would be helpful

Comment: I've solved this problem. I can achieve it by using modal not push. push is only used in navigation bar controller. without nav controller, I can make what I want. thanks your comments!